# How can I text a photo from Google Photos instead of a link?

Tags: sms, photos, google-photos

On my Pixel 2, I can include a photo in a text message in these two ways:

1. Open Messages app, select recipient, Hit "+", select photo on phone, touch "MMS" to send.
2. Open Google Photos app, select photo to send, touch "sharing" symbol, select recipient, touch "SEND".

In the first approach, the recipient receives the photo. In the second approach, the recipient is told I'm sharing an album, and they get a link to the photo.

I want the recipient to get the photo itself, not a link to it, but sometimes it's more convenient to choose the photo using the Photos app instead of the Messages app. How can I select a photo using the Google Photos app and then send that photo (as opposed to a link to it) in a text message?

Comment: Download that photo from Google Photos to the phone then send it to the recipient as you would with a normal one.

Comment: So there's no way to send the photo starting with Google Photos instead of with the Messages app? On iOS, I can do it either way, i.e., it works to choose a photo in Google Photos on my iPhone, "export" it to iMessage, then send as usual. There's no need to download it to the iPhone.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe No, there is no direct way. Download and send, or send from messages app.

Comment: In my s5 if i do option 2 it still sends the picture and not a link. Not sure why it's different by you

Comment: Could it be a Pixel-specific behavior? I'm new to Android, so I don't know how much variation there is between devices.

Comment: I figured out how to do it. After touching the "share" icon, you have to select the Messages app. Then you select the recipient and touch "MMS".

Comment: You should make your last comment an answer.

Comment: @garyp: I've now done it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Originally posted in the comments section on 11/5/17]

After touching the "share" icon, you have to select the Messages app. Then you select the recipient and touch "MMS".

Answer (score 1):

after clicking the share link, scroll down to the apps section and choose your preferred texting app, then choose the contact or conversation you would like to send the picture to.

Answer (score 0):

Know it all wanna be is my hero.  I have been trying to figure this out for days.  It's that simple.  Ignore all of the other well intended advice.  After you hit the share sign, choose messages and then choose recipient.  Attached picture to text the way you expect it to.

Comment: Agree. It took me some time to realize what was happening. I had the impression that there is no way to send the actual picture as attachment with Gmail. Then I figured it out: The share button in Google Foto already presents a field to enter an email adress. This share button would send the link. When one scrolls down to Gmail, the photo is treated like a normal file and is attached. Yay!